# how to install DataTable plugins?

Tags: datatables

I have downloaded the packages from this site https://datatables.net/download/packages 
 But not getting what is the next step.Can any one help me? 
Thanks

Comment: They also have a manual on that web site, where you can find a chapter about [Installation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation). Have you read this already? Do you have any specific problems?

Comment: yes i have read it already. They told "Simply download the latest version of DataTables, unzip and upload to your web-server. You will then have a directory such as DataTables-1.10.9 available on your server. " didnot get this two line..

Comment: What part of that instruction did you not get? Are you familiar with unzipping a file and uploading it to your web server?

Comment: Unzip then upload to server that was not getting.. Thank u so much for ur response I got my answer..